# What setting can cause a monitor to flicker under X11?

Tags: xorg, xorg.conf, display-settings

I've been dinking with the xorg.conf file on my system and now when I try to start X I get a flickering effect and no usable image. I *think* (and this is just a guess) that it's a settings out of bound error of some kind but I don't know what setting. I'm almost completely sure that the hardware is good given that everything is brand new and works just fine in text mode. ([HP LP3065 flat panel](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/382087-382087-64283-72270-3884471-3297215.ht) if that makes any difference)

Any ideas?

---

More information:

If I remove the xorg.conf file, the original problem goes away but the monitor shows off center and with corruption around the edges. If I just comment out everything in the file, I get the original problem back.

A little spulunking show I'm using a [Quadro FX 580](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_quadro_fx_580_us.html). If I switch to a different monitor (24" with lower res) things work.

Comment: Is your monitor a CRT?

Comment: flat panel LCD.

Comment: i got heavy flickering when trying to log into two xservers on the same hardware (laptop LCD, ati mobility radeon, one user into Xubuntu session and a different into Ubuntu/Gnome session, Ubuntu 10.04).  thre are a lot of different variables that come into play and troubleshooting gets ... complicated.

Comment: Sorry not a Linux user so excuse my ignorance... is this not a screen resolution issue?  that's why it goes away with a different monitor; try reading the manufactures recomended refresh rates to see if you can set your video setting to that of the monitor.  Possibly your .CFG file is setting the resolution/refresh to it's own parameters.  Also try pressing the auto button on the monitor it's self this will fix basic/ reset to default which can help eleviate other issues /possibly.

Comment: This behavior is sometimes caused when you insert a modeline manually or alter its parameters.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, I'd think you aren't outputting a screen resolution/refresh rate combo that the monitor support?